# Convergent Improper Integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I am analyzing the following integral
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx
$$
with $a,b>0$. Playing a little with the values I concluded that this integral is only convergent when $a=1$ and $b>0$ but I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas? Or maybe my trial-and-error attempts have failed?

Comment: As was mentioned in the answers, at $a\neq1$ the integral diverges: splitting the interval of integration, we get the sum of divergent integrals, which is generally not defined. But we can give meaning to the integral, if we agree to treat these divergent parts in a special way.

Comment: We can, for example, consider the integral in the principal value sense, i.e. define
$$I(a,b)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_0^{a-\epsilon}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx+\int_{a+\epsilon}^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx\right)$$
This limit exists:
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\ln\big(\frac ba\big)\ln(ba)+\pi^2}{2(a+b)};\quad I(1,b)=\frac{\ln^2b+\pi^2}{2(b+1)}$$
Such integrals have a deep connection with complex integration.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\lim_{x\to 1}{\log x\over x-1}=1$$ Therefore for $a=1$ there is no singularity at $x=1.$ As the integrand at $\infty$ behaves like $$x^{-2}\log x=(-x^{-1}-x^{-1}\log x)'$$ the integral is convergent for $a=1.$

For $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$ there is a singularity at $x=a.$ The integrand near $a$ behaves like ${\log a\over (a+b)(x-a)}$. Therefore the integral is divergent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't understand why when compared with $x^{-2}\log(x)$ the integral converges. Since $\int_0^\infty x^{-2}\log(x) dx$ diverges. Could you detail that part a little more? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

For the case $a\neq 1$, we can observe that the $(x+b)$ term is not relevant and by

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx=\int_0^{\frac a 2}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx+\int_{\frac a 2}^a\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx+$$

$$+\int_a^{2a}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx+\int_{2a}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-a)(x+b)}dx$$

we can observe that the first and latter integrals converges but the second one and the third one diverges for any $a\in \mathbb R^+\setminus\left\{1\right\}$.